# Does the mentioned approach to train a 100 GB dataset right way to go about it?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a 100 GB dataset and I want to train an ML model on it. I have 5 versions of this dataset each containing a different set of engineered features. I want to find out which version of the dataset provides the best performance. But training 5 different models on a 100GB dataset will be time-consuming. Therefore, I've decided to take 1 Gb subset of the original dataset and use the subset to find the best-performing version of engineered features.

Will this approach generalize to the original dataset? In other words, Will the set of engineered features that performs best on the 1GB subset also performs the best on the 100 GB dataset? Assuming that the 1 GB subset explains the variability of the 100 GB dataset ( subset is well represented )

Comment: _"Assuming that the 1 GB subset explains the variability of the 100 GB dataset"_. Just curious - how can you justify this assumption? Why not finding a 100MB subset of 100GB dataset and thus cut the training time and compute resources even more?

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak Great question. It is a supervised ML task. The label is a normal random variable. Since 100 GB is the population, I know the population mean and variance for the label. To justify the assumption I use the following method: 1) Convert label into 6 bins to account for 99.7% data 2) Take a random value from the normal distribution 3) Find which bin that value falls in and randomly pick a row from that bin 4) Repeat this 7 million times which equates to 1GB.